# Window overlay when phone is ringing

Tags: android

I'm trying to have a popup dialog like in true caller to show when I receive a call. I'm able to detect when the user gets a call using a broadcast receiver and I can add a window when the phone state is on. But if the phone is locked the popup dialog appears behind the caller screen.

```
telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    // CALL_STATE_RINGING
                    Log.d("MyReceiver", "I'm in " + state + " and the number is " + incomingNumber);
                    wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
                    params1 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT |
                                    LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                            LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                            LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                            LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                            LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
                            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);

                    params1.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
                    params1.height = 150;
                    params1.width = 512;
                    params1.x = 200;
                    params1.y = 200;
                    params1.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;

                    ly1 = new LinearLayout(context);
                    ly1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    ly1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    wm.addView(ly1, params1);
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

The window is not coming on top of the caller screen from Android version Lollipop and above. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by unlocking the screen using Keyguard manager before showing the window.

```
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) context .getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
final KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km .newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
kl.disableKeyguard();
```